# Any recent(not older than 2015) books that cover into detail aspects of a Digital camera like the sensor, ADC, DSP, analolgue pre- processor etc.?

Tags: camera

Manual of Photography is great but its last edition was published 13 years ago and Im guessing digital camera technology has changed quite a bit during this period. Any recommendations ??

Comment: Hm, sensors are still 14 bits, ADC is still 14 bits, dynamic range is still below 15. What do you expect to read?

Comment: Most of the improvements in digital camera technology since 2010 have been in the areas of sensor readout speed and image processing after the analog signal has been converted to digital information. There has been a trend to move ADC onto the sensor die itself in this time period. Unless you're doing astro work and worried about "star eaters" due to pre-ADC NR, there's really not much to add to what was around in 2010.

Answer (score 1):

I have a text called, Light and Lens, by Robert Hirsch. Published in 2018, ISBN 978-1-138-21302-9, its subtitle is photography in the digital age and has a a large chapter on digital image capture and lenses.